# Within snowflake stored procedure set variable and use it within the same procedure as a copy pattern

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a stored procedure to copy from the external stage (s3 bucket) and use a pattern for the file name. The pattern is based on the concatenated current date but I need to set a variable to use as a pattern. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_copy()
    RETURNS STRING
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT    
    EXECUTE AS CALLER
    AS
    $$
    SET my_Date=(select concat('.*', regexp_replace(current_date(),'-',''), '.*.parquet' );
    var sql_command = '
    COPY INTO table1
    FROM '@s3bucket'  
    (file_format  => PARQUET, pattern=>$my_Date) 
);
    '
    snowflake.execute(
        {
        sqlText: sql_command
        });
    return "Successfully executed.";
    $$;
```

Comment: You're mixing SQL and JavaScript with the line that starts `SET my_Date=` You can run a SQL statement that sets a session variable from inside a stored procedure, but it limits how you can call the procedure. You'll only be able to call it with caller's rights.

Comment: I made it this way just to show what I want to achieve. I wanted to understand, what is the correct syntax for implementing something like this. Also maybe there is a better way to populate my_Date besides making it a session variable?

Comment: As you can generate the current date in javascript, why not create my_Date purely in javascript? You then need to create sql_command by concatenating the required strings and variables together

Comment: @NickW that worked, thanks. If I want to close this post, should I vote for deleting it or post an answer/solution myself and mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can generate the current date in javascript, why not create my_Date purely in javascript?

You then need to create sql_command by concatenating the required strings and variables together